# Reporting Services: How To Fit PDF Export On One Page?

Tags: pdf, reporting-services

I've built a report in Reporting Services and when we browse to the report in Internet Explorer we want to be able to export the report in PDF format.  It works, but it was cutting off the columns to the right and displaying them on the next page (in PDF) because the page was too wide.  I changed the orientation to landscape and it still cut off the columns on the right.  Then I changed the page size to legal paper and it fits on one page, but we want the report on letter size paper.  Is there a way to compress the report to fit on letter size landscape?

Comment: There are Report Property Margins you can control (right click/Report Properties). Also the body itself has width properties - the body width plus the margins (left and right) cannot be wider than your paper or it will spill onto another page. For example if the Report properties have left/right margins of .25, and you want to print landscape on 8.5x11, the body of the report width cannot exceed 10.5 inches.

Comment: Even I have kind of same problem with SSDT 2017. In this AI world, why MS is unable to provide a easy and suitable solution?

Answer (score 5):

Here is how to get a report to fit on a letter page:

1. Click on the blank space outside of your report
2. Look at the properties and find interactive size. Set it to 11,8.5in.  Set your Margins to 0.5in, 0.5in, 0.5in, 0.5in
3. Click on the body and select properties.  Set the width to 10in and something less than 7.5 for the height.

Comment: I tired many possible ways, however unable to adjust. Any other clue?

Answer (score 1):

I was having this issue too. I set my margins to zero, which allowed me to print on 1 pdf page instead of 2.

Answer (score -1):

When you develop report from SpagoBI Studio
change setting of Master Page (next to Layout).

No need to change orientation but you need to
increase the width of report according to your number of columns and column with.

make sure it is greater than sum of all column's width (table width)

This will solve the issues